# $k$-algebra homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to ask if the following is true:

> Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra where $k$ is any field. If we have a $k$-algebra homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow k$, does it follow that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal of $A$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is a homomorphism of $k$-algebras, $k \to A \to k$ is the identity. In particular $f : A \to k$ is surjective. Hence, $A/\ker(f) \cong k$.

Answer (score 2):

As long as $f$ is not zero, the ideal $\ker(f)$ will have codimension $1$ and hence must be maximal.

Comment: $f$ can't be zero (unless your ring homomorphisms are not unital).

Comment: Why does the ideal have codimension 1?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_theorem

Comment: Sorry but I still can't see why. The link you gave me was about vector space dimension, which is not related to the dimension in rings...

Comment: Alternatively you can just say that $f(A)$ is ideal in $k$ so it has to be $k$. This means that $ker(f)$ is maximal.

Comment: @enoughsaid05 Well, your $k$-algebra $A$ is in particular a $k$-vector space, is it not?

Comment: @user52045: Thanks! That clears a lot.

Comment: @Rasmus: Yes.... but the dimension in vector space is different from the dimension in rings. It is not clear that the vector space codimension of 1 translates to codimension (ring theory sense) of 1. I might need to think a while.

Comment: @enoughsaid05: Every subspace of codimension 1 is a maximal (proper) subspace. In particular, every ideal of vector-space-codimesion 1 is a maximal ideal.